# setTimeout for sleep timer fails with back button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout, back

I have a sleep timer that will logout the user if their computer goes to sleep for more than 30 seconds.

If the user clicks the back button on the site one or more times, they get logged out, but it's not really consistent.

I know that `setTimeout()` is paused and then resumed when the user clicks the back button, so why is it logging out the user?

```
(function ($) {

/**
 * @property {number}     warningTimeout Time (ms) of the countdown until logout.
 * @property {number}     sleepInterval  Interval length in time (ms) to check if the computer went to sleep.
 * @property {function()} logout         Function to redirect user to logout screen.
 * @property {?string}    sleepTimer     Timeout ID of the timer that checks if the computer whent to sleep.
 * @property {?number}    sleepTime      Timestamp of the last time the sleepTimer timeout was executed.
 */
var session = {
    warningTimeout: 30000,  
    sleepInterval: 5000,         
    logout: function () {
        clearTimeout(session.sleepTimer);
        clearTimeout(session.keepaliveTimer);
        $(document).idleTimer('destroy');
        window.location.href = "index.php?q=logout";
    },
    sleepTimer: null,
    sleepTime: Date.now(),
};

/**
 * Logs out user if computer goes to sleep 
 */
session.sleepTimer = setTimeout(function sleeper() {
    var diff = Date.now() - session.sleepTime;
    session.sleepTime = Date.now();

    // If asleep for 30 seconds or more, logout
    if (diff >= session.warningTimeout) {
        session.logout();
    // Synchronize with the start time every run
    } else {
        session.sleepTimer = setTimeout(sleeper, session.sleepInterval - (diff % session.sleepInterval));
    }
}, session.sleepInterval);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you have a "working" example of this anywhere? My guess is that you're not using cookies or storing session variables. I haven't heard of using jQuery to manage time that effectively. Check out http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: @TimWilson I don't have a working example, our website is not open to everyone. I'm not using cookies or sessions yet, I just want the timer to work for now, then will add that in later. I want the timer to work for when the user has the page open. Logging out the user between page loads will require a different script.